# Unable to access function parent with event

Tags: angular, angular8

This is from my parent component html.

```
       <div class="section graph ltr">
                        <campaign-graph
                            (getLeads)="getLeadsForCampaign($event)"
                            [campaign]="campaign"
                            [leads]="campaign.leadTotal"
                            [leadsCount]="leadsSum"
                            [openLeadsCount]="openLeadsCountForCampaign"
                            [averagePosition]="averagePositionForCampaign"
                            [difference1stPlace]="difference1stPlaceForCampaign"
                        ></campaign-graph>
                    </div>
```

"campaign-graph" is the child, all of the field are getting fine in the child, but I am not entering "getLeadsForCampaign" on the parent.
    why? 
    Parent:
    `getLeadsForCampaign(campagin) {
        this.toChild = campagin;
        if (this.leadsSum > 0) {
            this.averagePositionForCampaign = this.leadsSum;
        }
    }`

child:

```
     @Input() leads: number;
        @Input() leadsCount: number;
        @Input() openLeadsCount: number;
        @Input() averagePosition: number;
        @Input() difference1stPlace: number;
        @Input() campaign: Campaign;
        @Output() getLeads: EventEmitter<Campaign> = new EventEmitter<Campaign>();
        current: Campaign;
        constructor(
            public moneyPipeC: RubikShekelPipe,
            private currentRouterC: ActivatedRoute,
            private readonly _exportServiceC: ExportService,
            private readonly _apiC: BestiapiService,
            _utilsC: UtilitiesService,
            private translate: TranslateService,
            private http: HttpClient,
            private authC: AuthService
        ) {
            super(currentRouterC, moneyPipeC, _exportServiceC);
        }

        fromParent(Campaign) {
            this.getLeads.emit(Campaign);
        }

        ngOnInit() {
            this.fromParent(this.current);
            this.dayFilter = EditField.optionFieldBuilder('agencies', this.translate.instant('CAMPAIGNS.FILTER_DAYS.TITLE'), []);

        }
```

Comment: It needs more info, like the error messages, if any, in the console.

Comment: *but not "getLeadsForCampaign" on the parent* - please eloborate. Are you pushing values to the `getLeads` event emitter in the child?

Comment: @MichaelD I am not getting any errors, what I want is to enter `getLeadsForCampaign` in the parent, That its not happend. I edited the post

Comment: @NavahPerkal: It looks like by the time you push the value `this.current` to emitter, it's still `undefined` because it isn't assigned any values.

Comment: but I should enter `getLeadsForCampaign` in the Parent before see the values in the child, no? Thanks @MichaelD

Answer (score 1):

Have you emitted the event from your child Component.Please see the example below:
Eg:this.getLeads.emit('something');
Please share your child component code as well for clear understanding of issue.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post. but the isuue is that I am calculate all the field in the parent and send it to the child. so the function should work on the parent Component!

Comment: If you have an example?